# Iterating ConcurrentQueue<T>

Tags: collections, .net-4.0, thread-safety

Is this a safe way of iterating [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)?

```
while (cq.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
{
    IIndexTask task;
    if (cq.TryDequeue(out task))
        task.Execute(service);
}
```

Comment: Calling Dequeue repeatedly will effectively go through the items in the queue, so there's no reason to iterate it as well.

Comment: @Brian - We will be dequeuing periodically so need to know how many times to call dequeue. I don't think Count is going to be thread safe?

Comment: But TryDequeue will tell you if the operation succeeded or not. What more do you need?

Comment: @Brian - the main reason is that we don't want to process the entire queue at once. For example, if we are queueing send email tasks, I may only want to process 100 at a time so I don't kill my mail server. I can adapt @LukeH example below to add a counter variable. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do this instead...

```
IIndexTask task;
while (cq.TryDequeue(out task))
{
    task.Execute(service);
}
```